# Variable ordering based on value Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query that are a number of positions that goes from A1 to A100, then B1 to B100, and so on.
I want to order this query so that the positions appear alphabetically in ascending order, but when it reaches the next letter, it goes descending, and keep this until the end of the table.

Here is an example.

```
SELECT
POSITION

FROM POSITION_TABLE
-------------------
POSITION
--------
A1
A2
...
A99
A100
B100
B99
B98
...
B2
B1
C1
C2
..
```

How can I do this ordering inside a query?

I tried ordering by the position using CASE, but I wanted something more generic, in case I needed to increase in size.

Comment: Will the letter part always be consenquentive snf complete? I mean, start with A, there will be B, C ... and for example.if there is E there will be D?

Comment: You are going to have issues sorting that alphabetically (as shown) in any direction, since `A10`, `A100` or `A1000` will always come *before* `A9` alphabetically. The only way to get that to sort correctly in any direction would be to include leading zeros: `A001, A002, ... A099, A100` and to limit the number of numerical digits in your string.

Comment: I think it is very unlikely you will manage this with pure SQL.  You could do this in your favourite programming language though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT position
FROM   (
  SELECT position,
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(position, '^\D+') AS leading_string,
         CASE MOD(DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(position, '^\D+')), 2)
         WHEN 1
         THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(position, '^\D+')
                ORDER BY TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(position, '\d+$')) ASC
              )
         ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(position, '^\D+')
                ORDER BY TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(position, '\d+$')) DESC
              )
         END AS rn
  FROM   position_table
)
ORDER BY
       leading_string,
       rn;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE position_table (POSITION) AS
SELECT 'A' || LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10 UNION ALL
SELECT 'B' || LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10 UNION ALL
SELECT 'C' || LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10 UNION ALL
SELECT 'D' || LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10;
```

Outputs:

| POSITION |
| --- |
| A1 |
| A2 |
| A3 |
| ... |
| A9 |
| A10 |
| B10 |
| B9 |
| ... |
| B3 |
| B2 |
| B1 |
| C1 |
| C2 |
| C3 |
| ... |
| C9 |
| C10 |
| D10 |
| D9 |
| ... |
| D2 |
| D1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/RrFfkKGc)